# How to declare a generic Class extending an annotation

Tags: java, java-annotations

I'm working on an annotation processor and I would pass to my class a parameter representing the annotation to manage, something like: `Class<? extends @interface> annotationClass`

Unfortunately this does not compile. The only way I can compile is using a raw type `Class` but in this way when I try something like

```
roundEnvironment.getElementsAnnotatedWith(annotationClass)
```

the returned type is an `Object` instead of a `javax.lang.model.element.Element`

```
public Map<ClassName, List<ElementInfo>> initClassesToGenerate(Class annotationClass, ElementKind elementKind, RoundEnvironment roundEnvironment) {

        Map<ClassName, List<ElementInfo>> result = new HashMap<>();

        // init map

        for (Element annotatedElement : roundEnvironment.getElementsAnnotatedWith(annotationClass)) {

            TypeElement typeElement = (TypeElement) annotatedElement;
            ClassName className = ClassName.get(typeElement);
            if (!result.containsKey(className)) {
                result.put(className, new ArrayList<>());
            }
        }

        return result;
}
```

Comment: `A extends Annotation`

Comment: it's working, i'm a stupid :D thank you

Comment: No problem.  Answer form below is more useful (thanks @cameron1024).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<T extends Annotation>`. You can then use `Class<T>` to reference classes of annotations.